# Ruby on Rails: How can i remove/delete/sanitize script, style tags from text input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sanitize

```
<%= form_for @post.comments.new do |f| %>
    Name:<%= f.text_field :name %><br/>
    Email:<%= f.text_field  :email %><br/>
    Body:<%= f.text_area :content %><br/>
    <%= submit_tag "Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to delete/remove/sanitize `<script>..</script>` and `<style>..</style>` tags.

Other option is if there any script,style tags then the input field will be considered as empty. And then the comment will not be saved.

How can i remove those tags and the code inside those tags? And how can i remove html tags too and the contents inside html tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, nothing in Rails 3 can do this. Use the [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) gem.

Add `gem 'sanitize'` to your Gemfile, and run `bundle install`. That alone should do it.

Comment: Why would i use Sanitize gem? Isn't there any function/method in rails 3 to do this?

Comment: @guru, not that I know of. They can't remove specific tags off a document.

Comment: Where would i add these lines ? require 'rubygems'
require 'sanitize'

Comment: Add `gem 'sanitize'` to your Gemfile, and run `bundle install`. That alone should do it.

Comment: But the <br/> is being translated by '&nbsb'. Is it possible to remove <br/> with that sanitize gem ?

Comment: It looks, there is already a sanitizehelper, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize, Is it possible to get the same result using it instead of sanitize gem ?

Answer (score 11):

I've been using sanitize for this exact purpose. It's been working great.

Add a constant to your app:

```
YourApp::SANITIZE_FILTER = {
  :remove_contents => ['script']
}
```

Then you can add a helper method:

```
 def sanitize_content(content)
   content = Sanitize.clean(content, YourApp::SANITIZE_FILTER)
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

```
string = '<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>'
strip_tags(string) #This Will give you "Hi"
```

Comment: I tried strip_tags in irb> but got error,1.9.2-p180 :010 > strip_tags(string) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `strip_tags' for main:Object
 from (irb):10
 from /path/to/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'

Comment: In `rails console` you can run `helper.strip_tags(str)`

Comment: I got,  1.9.2-p180 :015 > helper.strip_tags(string) 
NameError: undefined local variable or method `helper' for main:Object
 from (irb):15
 from /path/to/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'

Comment: If using in an `rails console` try `include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` first.

Comment: `strip_tags` removes everything. If you want to scrub specific tags, you'll want to use something like:
`scrubber = Rails::Html::TargetScrubber.new`
`scrubber.tags = ['script', 'style']`

# in the view
`<%= sanitize @comment, scrubber: scrubber %>`